# Adding two classes with arithmetic math

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to add two classes together with a simple arithmetic addition

The class i've written is a Vector3 class
it looks like this

```
public class Vector3 {

public float x, y, z;

public Vector3(){
    x = 0.0f;
    y = 0.0f;
    z = 0.0f;
}

public Vector3(float _x, float _y, float _z){
    this.x = _x;
    this.y = _y;
    this.z = _z;
}
public Vector3 add(Vector3 other){
    Vector3 temp = new Vector3(this.x+other.x, this.y+other.y, this.z+other.z);
    return temp;
}

}
```

I have added the add method in order to be able to add vectors together temporarily. but i really want to be able to just type vectorA+vectorB instead of having to type vectorA.add(vectorB)

is there a way to do this. i know you can do it in python.

Comment: That's called *operator overloading* and [has been addressed on Stack Overflow previously for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java).

Comment: If you like that, come to the dark side, C#! We have all the cool stuff for ages: lambdas, type inference, nonweird generics (debatable), operator overloads, extension methods, properties (no more getx, setx), "streaming operations" (LINQ), etc.

Comment: I wish I could use c#. But I'm studying software engineering. And we have to use java for the first two semesters :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put it bluntly, you can't. Java does not allow the user to define operator overloads. You will have to continue to use the `Vector3::add(Vector3)` method that you have already created.

Java is Java, Python is Python (C++ is C++, and C is C); they are all different languages that do different things. You shouldn't expect one thing to work because it works in another language.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support operator overloading, but a similar language, C#, does. (C# and Java are very similar and are usually compared with each other)

The Unity engine, which uses C# scripting, already defines a [Vector3](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) class, with several overloaded operators (including + and -).

There, you can do something like:

```
Vector3 result = new Vector3(1, 2, 3) + new Vector3(4, 5, 6);
```

Of course, if you cannot change your programming language (either by choice or because of the framework used), then this is not an option, and you should stick to using the `add()` method.